# Pandas: Concatenate from two rows in rolling window

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Series like this using Pandas

```
>>> kk
0        0
1     2976
2     5664
3     8640
4    11520
```

And I want roll a two-item window to get a new series like this:

```
>>> pp
0           NaN
1        0-2976 
2     2976-5664
3     5664-8640
4    8640-11520
```

As you can see I need to access multiple rows per group in the window
What would be the function to get `pp` from `ss` where:

```
ss = kk.rolling(2)
```

Comment: You need string concatenation but as far as I know, rolling or expanding doesn't work on dtype objects so you may have to roll out a solution with loops.

Answer (score 3):

For a two-row window, you do not really need `rolling`. `shift` works just fine:

```
ss = kk.shift(1) + '-' + kk
#0           NaN
#1        0-2976
#2     2976-5664
#3     5664-8640
#4    8640-11520
#dtype: object
```